# Broadband is FTTP more reliable than FTTC for similar speeds?

Tags: networking, broadband

I currently pay £26/month for TalkTalk Fibre To The Cabinet (FTTC) Broadband which is advertised as 67 Mbs but in practice, I get about 62 Mbs and occasionally drops to 20 Mbs or less, and occasionally as much as 70 Mbs.

Recently Vodafone has started offering 63 Mbs for £22/month on newly installed Fibre To The Premises (FTTP). They also offer 900 Mbs £55/month but I'm not prepared to pay this much.

My question is:

Are the speeds from FTTP more consistent than for FTTC? Or does FTTP experience the same occasional drops in speed that FTTC has?

Comment: Your speed drops are most likely caused by the ISP (or the local network segment) being overloaded.

Comment: It's all dependant on contention ratio [how many people are 'sharing the wire']. They're no longer allowed to advertise it as 67 if you can only get 20. Complain every time it drops below advertised speed. I pay for 200mbps & get 200mbps day & night, 365 a year [barring the occasional hiccup] https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1SwP.png Mine is FTTC.